# React updating elements from one file to other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Hello Guys I am a newbie and trying to learn React. I want to access the state of counters.js from counter.js in the delete button. I tried to print but the output is giving as undefined. The expected output is the button id clicked. Please somebody help. and can someone suggest me a good course to learn React and front-end development?

**counter.js**

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  }
  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (<div>
      {this.props.children}
      <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
      <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">Delete</button>
    </div>);
  }
  formatCount() {
    const {value} = this.state;
    return value === 0
      ? "Zero"
      : value;
  }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.value === 0
      ? "warning"
      : "primary";
    return classes;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

**Counters.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 4
      }, {
        id: 2,
        value: 0
      }, {
        id: 3,
        value: 0
      }, {
        id: 4,
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    console.log('Event Handler Called', counterId);
  }
  render() {

    return (<div>
      {this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>))}

    </div>)
  }
}

export default Counters;
```

**console**
[image: the console output is returning undefined but expected is the button clicked (1,2)],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change word key to any other letter) and it should works fine

```js
{this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter key={counter.id}
to 
{this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter a={counter.id} 
and this line also
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.key)}
to 
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.a)}
```

also you can add a key in this way

```
(counter, i) => (<Counter key={i} a={counter.id}
```

here is your working solution in two files

Counters.js

```js
export default class Counters extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            counters: [
              {
                id: 1,
                value: 4
              }, {
                id: 2,
                value: 0
              }, {
                id: 3,
                value: 0
              }, {
                id: 4,
                value: 0
              }
            ]
          };

          this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
    }
  
  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    console.log(counterId)
    console.log('Event Handler Called', counterId);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
      {this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter a={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>))}

    </div>)
  }
}
```

counter.js

```js
import React from 'react'


class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value
        }

        this.getBadgeClasses = this.getBadgeClasses.bind(this)
        this.formatCount = this.formatCount.bind(this)
    }
    handleIncrement = () => {
        
      this.setState({
        value: this.state.value + 1
      })
    }
  
    render() {
      return (<div>
        {this.props.children}
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.a)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">Delete</button>
      </div>);
    }
    formatCount() {
      const {value} = this.state;
      return value === 0
        ? "Zero"
        : value;
    }
  
    getBadgeClasses() {
      let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
      classes += this.state.value === 0
        ? "warning"
        : "primary";
      return classes;
    }
  }
  
  export default Counter;
```

Comment: still the same no change

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link :
[Passing function to components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

and don't forget to bind your function to component instance.

Answer to second question:
If you have github student account (for free access), checkout [Frontend Masters](https://frontendmasters.com/). It is an excellent resource for frontend development.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a component’s state from outside the component. As it’s stated in the official React documentation:

> State is similar to props, but it is private and fully controlled by
> the component.

Basically there are two approaches for “exchanging” the state between components:

1. **From parent components to child components with props:** Just as you did with the value property of your Counter component
2. **From child components to parent components with event handlers:**
   If certain actions should trigger a state change of a parent’s component you need to inform the parent about the action with an event handler. You already did that with your onDelete handler.

These are the only two mechanisms in React to "exchange" the state. In your case I suggest to remove the state of your Counter component and to use the value property instead. Additionally you need to add an onIncrement handler (just as you did with onDelete) and move the handleIncrement function to your Counters component. Observe that you need to pass the counter’s id to the handleIncrement function now (since the Counters component does not know which child component triggered the event).

If you apply these changes, the Counter component is stateless and the state of all counters is controlled by the Counters component. Nevertheless since you pass the state via the value property it still gets updated each time the state changed.

For diving into react I suggest to do the React tutorial for beginners (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) – your issue is addressed here throughout the tutorial (look for “lifting up the state”) and afterwards you could continue with the official documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html).

Comment: I got the 2 points about changing the state, but I have done it and passed the id also so with id reference is present why am I getting a value of undefined?

Comment: And thanks for the resource options I will refer it definitely

Comment: In the Counter component you are passing this.props.id to your onDelete function. But you did not set a property of id (thus this.props.id is undefined). Just pass the id to your Counter component: <Counter id={counter.id} .../>

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only **key**, **onDelete** and **value** props to  component.

```
{this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>))}
```

And you are trying to access this.props.id on delete button click inside counter.js file.

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">Delete</button>
```

you should use this.props.key on delete button click instead of this.props.id. The correct delete button code will be like

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.key)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">Delete</button>
```

You can go through [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) official documents for better learning of React.

Comment: There was no change in the output by replacing id with the key.

Comment: @GauravKulkarni Can you print what are all the props you are getting inside counter.js file ?

Comment: What are the props you are getting?

Comment: Have you changed id with key ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting undefined is because you are not passing id prop for Counter component

```
  {this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>))}
```

So passing id prop will work as your expectation:

```
  {this.state.counters.map(counter => (<Counter id={counter.id} key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}/>))}
```

This is one of the reasons we need some type check tools like PropTypes or Typescript so this kind of mistake can be avoided at compile time.
The best resource for learning React is actually React official documentation
https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html
Once you can digest this already then next step can subscribe Medium to get a lot of good reads so you can have deeper understandings from many aspects and use cases.

Comment: Tried this also but the error is the same, I added super also then also not done.

Comment: @GauravKulkarni: strange. I changed the same thing and it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cache-lr55j